# One community or More than One Commmunity

Tags: partner-communities

We want to create a partner community to allow the partner to access and view cases and reports. However, the boarder expects that when the partner user access the community, he will see the logo of his company instead of our. We have a lot of partners, is this possible through visualforce? Or should we create one community for each partner? Or better to create a website intetgrated with salesforce to allow partner to access and see the reports related to cases and the cases recordo to view/edit?

Comment: I'm not an expert on communities but it should be possible with one community. When you reference "partners" in your question I think, in salesforce speak, you mean accounts. And yes when you create the community I believe a user is created as a contact within an account. So when that user logs in they have access to only related information... I maybe wrong so let's hope someone else replied...I would recommend trying it out in a developer org if you don't have a license or a sandbox if you do.

Comment: @n34_panda  , thank you for your reply. Yes, with sharing rules, I can make accessible only the records that user is the owner or bases in some criteria. However, I would like to know if it's possible to create visualforce pages in the partner community, once the stakeholder expects that when the partner access the partner community, he will see the logo of his company, not only of our company. Do you knkow if I can use visualforce page in the partner community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=limits_communities_max_number_of_communities.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> **Maximum Number of Communities Limit**
>
> You can have up to 100 communities in your Salesforce org. Active, inactive, and preview communities, including Force.com sites, count against this limit.
>
> To see this limit in your org, from Setup enter Communities in the Quick Find box, then select All Communities. The Maximum number of communities field displays 100.

In essence, you only want to have one community, not one for each of your "partners".

From your description, it doesn't sound to me as though you need a "Partner Community" since you only want to view cases and reports. There are many other less expensive licenses that can do what you want. See [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US&type=0) for a comparison.

As for branding, if your users are all registered users, you can do what you've described using a solution which serves content that's dependent on the `user.accountId` property. This can be done via a variety of means the most common of which would be custom CSS but could also be formula based as well using a "Content Management Solution" as with normal web site design (beyond the scope of this forum).

Comment: is possible to edit cases through the css page for instance? I agree with you and I also through about a website (portal) instead of a community.

Comment: I'm not certain I follow your question. You could customize the CSS that applies to the Cases page and have that display custom content that's in the context of the current user. I hope that answers your question. I don't believe you'd be able to access Cases other than to submit one through a website. Look into Salesforce Sites for more on what you could do if you wanted to go that direction.